# How do I make a remote controlled fan turn on with the light switch?

Tags: bedroom, ceiling-fan

I have installed the fan, the remote works perfectly but when you turn the light switch on the fan does not light up you have to find the remote and use that to turn on the light
Help???

Comment: Are you just wanting the fan to come on when you turn the light on, but still have the remote option to turn it off when you don't want it running (IE: if left on when the light is turned off, have the fan come back on when the light is turned on)? Also, what make/model of fan did you install?

Answer (score 2):

And this is why I hate remote controlled fans.

You have two options: One remove the switch and replace with a one gang remote for the brand of fan you have.  Example, [this one](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Hampton-Bay-Ceiling-Fan-Wall-Control-9050H/202801200?N=5yc1vZbvmu).

The other, which is my preferred, is to hardwire the fan by removing the remote unit.  If the ceiling box was already wired for ceiling fans with two separate switched hots then all you need to do is change the switches for ones designed to control the fan speed.  If you only have a single switched hot, can you replace the switch and remote unit with a wired remote like this [one](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Lutron-Maestro-1-Amp-Single-Pole-7-Speed-Combination-Fan-and-Light-Control-White-MA-LFQHW-WH/100576179?N=5yc1vZbvmw).  This will transmit the light/fan control over the power wire to the fan unit.